# SQL query and nullifying variables

Tags: sql, variables

I'm trying to run this query but its returning nothing. its getting the users input as variables to the query. there is one thing that i have to mention which is when ever the user leaves the `batch_number`s`textbox empty, the query should return all the batches of the`organization_ID`. here is the query:

```
SELECT Nvl(a.ORGANIZATION_ID, ' '), 
       Nvl(a.FILE_TYPE, ' '), 
       Nvl(a.BATCH_NUMBER, ' '), 
       Nvl(a.FILE_NAME, ' '), 
       Nvl(TOTAL_ANB_RECORDS, 0) 
FROM   PAYMENT B, 
       PAYROLL A 
WHERE  b.ORGANIZATION_ID = a.ORGANIZATION_ID 
       AND a.ORGANIZATION_ID = '1176' 
       AND PAYMENT_TYPE = '1' 
       AND Nvl(PAYMENT_STATUS, 'a') = '5' 
       AND ( BM_BATCH_INDC = '0' 
              OR BM_BATCH_INDC = '1' 
              OR BM_BATCH_INDC = '3' ) 
       AND b.FILE_TYPE = a.FILE_TYPE 
       AND b.FILE_BATCH_NUMBER = a.BATCH_NUMBER 
       AND ( b.FILE_BATCH_NUMBER = '"+textBox.text.ToString()+"' 
              OR b.FILE_BATCH_NUMBER IS NULL ) 
       AND b.PAYMENT_PATH = '01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if it is blank data is coming as NULL

just write

```
AND b.FILE_BATCH_NUMBER = NVL(a.BATCH_NUMBER,b.FILE_BATCH_NUMBER)
```

in the place of

```
AND b.FILE_BATCH_NUMBER = a.BATCH_NUMBER 
       AND ( b.FILE_BATCH_NUMBER = '"+textBox.text.ToString()+"' 
              OR b.FILE_BATCH_NUMBER IS NULL )
```

if Batch_number is null it will return true for all file_batch_number